# Text Classification & Recommendation

Tags: python, machine-learning

I'm trying to create a machine learning algorithm, for address classification or similar address classification, for rural(Villages) areas. I have a historical data, which includes list of Addresses (Independent Variable), Village Name (Independent Variable) Pin-Codes (Independent Variable), Customer Mobile Number and Route No (Dependent Variable). Route No is for delivery cart, which will help them to cover maximum number of delivery destination in that area.

**Challenges -**

1. "Address" can be miss spelled.
2. "Villages Name" can be null.
3. "Pin-codes" can be wrong.

**Good Thing -**

Not all the independent variables can be wrong/null at the same time.

Now the point of creating this algorithm is for selecting the best Route Number, on the basis of "Address", "Villages", "Pin-Codes", and Historical Data(In which we have manually selected the Route for delivery carts).

I'm the beginner, i'm confused how to do this which process is to use.

Tasked I have done.

**Address cleaning -** Removed short words, Removed Big Words, Removed Stop Words.

Now trying to do it with word vector, but i'm not able to do that.

Answer (score 1):

for this first you'll have to build a dataset first - consisting the names of as many villages as you can! because many villages have similar names so identifying a typo is pretty difficult and risky! there is a difference of one or two letters. So, bigger dataset is better.
Then, try to use [TF-IDF](https://towardsdatascience.com/machine-learning-nlp-text-classification-using-scikit-learn-python-and-nltk-c52b92a7c73a) on the combination of village name and PIN code ([this link may be helpful for Indian data](https://data.gov.in/catalog/all-india-pincode-directory#web_catalog_tabs_block_10)) or you can go for fuzzy logic.
Hope it helps! Happy coding!